# Cross Browser Platform Data Storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, sqlite, cross-browser

I am creating a Cross browser Platform Web Application (HTML, JS, CSS), However I require a strong database storage that I can query on the client using JS. Web SQL/SQLite seems to be the best way to go BUT there is no support for it in IE. Does anyone know of any other querable client storage out there. or a working implementation of embedding SQLite "like" functions into the browser.

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills#web-sql-database

Comment: cant you use cookie and model can be XML or JSON.

Comment: seriously? you would use this in a live application?

Answer (score 0):

The [Web Storage API](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/) is available in all major browsers including mobile and desktop. I haven't used it before, but from my research I can tell that it doesn't use SQL queries. It seems to be the best option, even so I would recommend still using a fallback for browser that won't support the API (for example anything before IE8).

Hope this works out for you!